# Second order stochastic dominance

Tags: risk

I have two very basic questions about second order stochastic dominance (SOSD):

1. Am I right in thinking that this is only a partial order, i.e. you can find a pair of lotteries such that neither SOSD the other?
2. Could it be that, if we only consider lotteries with equal means, SOSD is then a complete order? [I suspect not...]

Comment: See Theorem 4.2 here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2015/lecture-notes-and-slides/MIT14_123S15_Chap4.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to **2.** is **no**.

One way to see this is from MWG's Property 6.D.2: $F$ SOSD $G$ if and only if
\begin{equation}
\int_0^xF(t)\mathrm dt \le \int_0^xG(t)\mathrm dt \quad\text{for all }x.
\end{equation}
[Dixit](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Edixitak/Teaching/EconomicsOfUncertainty/Slides&Notes/Notes04.pdf) calls the two integrals *super-cumulative* functions of $F$ and $G$, respectively. Hence, a characterization of SOSD is that the super-cumulative of the dominating distribution always lies below the super-cumulative of the dominated distribution. (This is reminiscent of the characterization of FOSD as the *cdf* of the dominating distribution always lying below the *cdf* of the dominated one.)

For a counterexample, we only need to come up with distributions $F$ and $G$ such that their super-cumulatives cross. Here's one:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\begin{cases}
0.1 & x\in\{0,6\}\\
0.4 & x\in\{2,4\}\\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}\\
g(x)&=\begin{cases}
\frac13 & x\in\{1,3,5\}\\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Both distributions have the same mean of $3$, but as the following figure shows, their super-cumulatives ($S_F$ and $S_G$) cross at several points, and so neither distribution SOSD the other.

[image]

Here, $S_F(x)=\int_0^x F(t)\mathrm dt = \int_0^x\int_0^tf(s)\mathrm ds\mathrm dt$, and $S_G$ is similarly defined. Since $f$ and $g$ are probability mass functions, the cdf's $F$ and $G$ are step-functions (shown below). Integrating the step-functions yields the continuous and piece-wise linear $S_F$ and $S_G$ above.

[image]

---

**Edit**

As OP noted in a comment, "ALL risk averse people with iso-elastic utility ($u=x^\alpha$, $\alpha\in(0,1)$) prefer gamble $G$ to gamble $F$". The negative answer above suggests that there must be a concave function with which $F$ is preferred to $G$. Here is an example:
\begin{equation} 
u(x)=\begin{cases} 2x& x\le 2\\ 4& x>2 \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
This function is concave, and $\mathbb E_F(u)=3.6>3.\overline{33}=\mathbb E_G(u)$.

Comment: @Giskard: There was indeed a mistake in the original graph (I plotted the wrong rows of the functional values). Thanks for catching that. Your other concerns are addressed in the edit.

Comment: +1 I now see where I went wrong and deleted my comment where I was misled.

Comment: @HerrK. thanks this looks persuasive. Though one thing I find strange is that ALL risk averse people with iso-elastic utility ($u = x^\alpha$, $\alpha \in (0, 1)$) prefer gamble $G$ to gamble $F$. Can you construct a (concave) utility function which leads to a preference for $F$?

Comment: Great example! (Though you have a typo and have written $x > 4$ not $x > 2$)

Answer (score 7):

The answer to 1.

Your conjecture is correct. Consider lotteries $A,B$ where $A$ guarantues a payoff of 1 while $B$ yields 0 or 4, each with 50% probability.

$B$ does not SOSD $A$, as you can easily find an agent risk averse enough that they will prefer $A$, e.g. an agent whose preferences are described by $u(x) = \ln(x)$.

$A$ does not SOSD $B$ either, as $E(B) > E(A)$, meaning an agent with $u(x) = x$ would prefer $B$.

Comment: Yes this seems right. I guess one should be able to construct similar examples (e.g. with asymmetric distributions?) even when means are equal?

Comment: @afreelunch I don't think so, the trade off here is definitely between expected value and risk. I recommend taking the "accept tick" back, and waiting for an answer to 2. :)

Comment: Yes good point. For what it is worth, I have tried and failed to come up with counterexamples to 2

Comment: @Bayesian I did, perhaps I am missing something. Using notation from there, assuming $E(x) = E(y)$ and $\epsilon = y-x$, is $E(\epsilon|x) = 0$ trivial? Without this, $E(x) = E(y)$ does not imply that either variable is a mean-preserving spread of the other.

Comment: The $E[\epsilon|x]=0$ is part of the definition of a mean-preserving spread, no?
My arguments was based on statement 1 & 3 of Thm 4.2 being equivalent.

Comment: @Bayesian All these only hold if $G$ is a mean preserving spread of $F$. Seems like this does not follow from equal expected value. Will try to construct a counterexample.

Comment: Could not get one. Seems like $G$ and $F$ would need to have several intersection points in the interior of the domain, so the functions will not have simple formulas, or I may be wrong and a counterexample could be impossible.

Comment: I believe this is a standard result, and I just posted the first google hit. Before you put too much effort into constructing a counterexample, we can look for a more convincing proof.

Comment: @afreelunch I recommend accepting the [Herr K.'s answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/43680/1601), because it is complete in itself: the negative answer to 2. is also a negative answer to 1.